# How to define different required methods in this Java program of array manipulation?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
package Exercises;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ArrayPlusN {

public static void createArray(int indeces){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int valueAdded, y = 0;
    int[] arraySet = new int[indeces];
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySet.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("Enter element #%s: ",i+1);
        arraySet[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("These are the elements in your array: ");
    for(int i:arraySet){
        System.out.printf("%s ", i);
    }
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.print("Enter a number to add in each of your Array's element: ");
    valueAdded = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("These are the elements in your array when we added "+ valueAdded + " to each: ");
    for(int i:arraySet){
        arraySet[y]=i+valueAdded;
        System.out.printf("%s ", i+valueAdded);
        y++;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int indeces;
    System.out.print("Enter how many array index/indeces you want: ");
    indeces = in.nextInt();
    createArray(indeces);

}
}
```

Well to start things up, i'm trying to make a program where it will add a value on each element in the array, by getting user input of how many index that user wants to make, elements of the said array and the value to be added on the said array. There's no error in this code though you can copy paste it but im asking if i can do it as OOP. i don't think that this is OOP, anybody can help? I mean i wanted to seperate all those functions on each methods, is that possible? i tried it but i can't seem to know on how to call another variable from another method. i wanted to make createArray, fillArray and addElement methods to make it look more OOP rather than just making 1 createArray with all the functions in it.

Comment: I think you will get better support here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OOP - [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). You've sprinkled that `Scanner` everywhere. Move the calculations in one place. Move the user input in other.

Comment: @Bakudan can you please post a sample here, i wanted to learn more type of coding oop programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code defining the **main()**, **createArray()**, **fillArray()** and **addElement()** methods; calls the methods in the order needed and accomplishes the task in the manner you want.

```
package Exercises;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayPlusN {
static int arraySet[];

    public void createArray(int indeces){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int valueAdded, y = 0;
        arraySet = new int[indeces];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayPlusN object=new ArrayPlusN();
        int indeces;
        System.out.print("Enter how many array index/indeces you want: ");
        indeces = in.nextInt();
        object.createArray(indeces);
        object.fillArray();
        object.addElement();
    }

    public void fillArray(){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<arraySet.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter element number "+(i+1));
            arraySet[i]=in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The elements of your array are");
        for(int i:arraySet)
        System.out.print(i+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void addElement(){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value to be added to each element");
        int valueAdded = in.nextInt();
        int y=0;
        System.out.println("These are the elements in your array when we added "+ valueAdded + " to each: ");
        for(int i:arraySet){
             arraySet[y]=i+valueAdded;
            System.out.printf("%s ", i+valueAdded);
            y++;
        }
    }
}
```

The **arraySet** array is declared as a global static one. All the methods are declared as **public void**. The arrays are called in the **main()** method with the object **object** of class **ArrayPlusN** in order and gets the job done. Hope it helps you.